# How to make Google Keyboard use word usage in predictions

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct

I use the word "smash" a lot as a short version of Super Smash Bros. Yet, every time I try to type smash, Google Keyboard turns it into "snag". Doesn't Google Keyboard use word usage in word prediction? How do I turn it on?

P.S. I'm using the swipe feature.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > Language & Input (or Language & Keyboard)

From there there are two settings, one is under keyboard > word suggestions (and make your choice of preferences from the menu); the other is 
Personal dictionary (or User dictionary, depending on the phone). Click on Add and have at smashing!